# Vim /usr/bin/bash: /s: No such file or directory

Tags: neovim, terminal, microsoft-windows

Repost from [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69259368/vim-usr-bin-bash-s-no-such-file-or-directory); I read a comment which directed me here saying it would be more helpful.

Just set up nvim; unfortunately, the following error is plaguing the setup. Whenever I try to install or change plugins or use Vimtex, it will throw the same error message just about everywhere: /usr/bin/bash: /s: No such file or directory. Similar error occurs when I use :checkhealth; the exact error message is below:

```bash
## terminal
  - ERROR: command failed: infocmp -L
    /usr/bin/bash: /s: No such file or directory
```

Additionally, I am using Windows, and here is my config file (switched to a minimal config to see if things would change, but the issue still persists):

```
set backspace=2         " backspace in insert mode works like normal editor
syntax on               " syntax highlighting
filetype indent on      " activates indenting for files
set autoindent          " auto indenting
set number              " line numbers
colorscheme desert      " colorscheme desert
set nobackup            " get rid of anoying ~file
filetype plugin indent on
" show existing tab with 4 spaces width
set tabstop=4
" when indenting with '>', use 4 spaces width
set shiftwidth=4
" On pressing tab, insert 4 spaces
set expandtab
```

Does anyone know what is causing the error and how to fix it? Would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: What system are you using? Windows? Linux? macOS? Do you have a nvim configuration file? What does it look like?

Comment: Using Windows, and using a minimal nvim config; I will add it into my post.

Comment: Cheers; I don't have any experience running (Neo)Vim on Windows I'm afraid, so I'm not entirely sure. I did find this on the issue tracker though: https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/14605

Comment: Are you using cygwin or msys or something similar that comes with a bash?

Comment: Yes, using git bash. It is default terminal setting that we use for classes in school.

Comment: looks like the given issue mentioned by @MartinTournoij in that case. You may want to explicitly configure your shell related options in that case. That may or may not work.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Please [edit] in the various `shell` related options to your post

Answer (score 2):

On windows, by default `shell=cmd.exe` and `shellcmdflag=/s /c`. Most probably somewhere in your config you set `shell=bash`, but did not adjust `shellcmdflag`. Set shellcmdflag when you adjust the shell.

```
if isexecutable('/usr/bin/bash')
     set shell=bash
     set shellcmdflag=-c
endif
```

There are also other `shell*` variables you have to modify. See [How can neovim on Windows be configured to use gitbash as the shell without breaking temp files?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/22869/how-can-neovim-on-windows-be-configured-to-use-gitbash-as-the-shell-without-brea)